# Problems installing mod_wsgi in windows. RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, apache, mod-wsgi, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Django project window with XAMPP, but I'm getting this error at the stage of installing mod_wsgi:

```
RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found. Set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment to its location.
```

Here is my set command result:
The thing is i already set my MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR to "c:\xampp\apache"

```
HOMEPATH=\Users\Ultimate
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Ultimate\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\HEALNSERVER
MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR = "c:\xampp\apache"
```

[image: here is a screenshot]

[image: here is another]
[image: here is the last one]